# Alexa Skill with cheerio

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, cheerio, alexa-voice-service

Hello I'm trying to use cheerio in a Alexa Skill to get data from website and add in skill. 
The code of intent

```
const HelloWorldIntentHandler = {
canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
        && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'all_titles';
},
handle(handlerInput) {
    //Lógica para speak output
    var options = {
        uri: 'https://es.pagetest.com/',
        transform: function (body) {
            return cheerio.load(body);
        }
    };

    rp(options)
    .then(function ($) {
        var arr_response = []
        var titles = $('.ms-short-title');
        titles.each((i, a) =>{
            if(a.parent.attribs.title !== undefined)arr_response.push(a.parent.attribs.title);
        });

        const speakOutput = insert_in_string(arr_response);

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            //.reprompt('add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond')
            .getResponse();
        function insert_in_string (arr_titulars){
            var string_text = '';
            for(var titular of arr_titulars){
                string_text += titular + ' Siguiente titular. ';
            }
            return string_text;
        }
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        return err;
    });

}
```

};

I have tested the logic locally and it works ok, by putting it in alexa code editor, in test, return error message, but not a trace
¿Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Alexa-hosted Skills, you will have CloudWatch integration already built-in.  Simply go to your Amazon Developer Console, navigate to your Skill's **Code** tab, scroll to the bottom and click the **Logs: Amazon CloudWatch** link on the bottom left.

Now, every time that you `console.log`, it will be sent to CloudWatch.  So, in your `catch` handler, add `console.log(err)` and you should be able to see what's going wrong.

This blog post might also help: https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/71ac4c05-9e33-41d2-abbf-472ba66126cb/3-tips-to-troubleshoot-your-custom-alexa-skill-s-back-end

Comment: I will try to try. Thanks!